# How can I solve 'Duplicate Constructor' error in Haxe?

Tags: constructor, duplicates, haxe

In Haxe, I created a class named **MyClass** like:

```
class MyClass {

    var score: String;

    public function new (score: Int) {
        this.score = Std.string(score);
    }

    public function new (score: String) {
        this.score = score;
    }
 }
```

I need multiple constructors but Haxe does not allow me to do. It throws this error from building phase:

```
*.hx:*: lines * : Duplicate constructor
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is known as *method overloading*, which is not supported by Haxe apart from [externs](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-externs.html) (but [might be in the future](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe-evolution/pull/14#issuecomment-423530189)). There's multiple ways you could work around this.

A common workaround in the case of constructors would be to have a static "factory method" for the second constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    var score:String;

    public function new(score:String) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public static function fromInt(score:Int):MyClass {
        return new MyClass(Std.string(score));
    }
}
```

---

You could also have a single constructor that accepts both kinds of arguments:

```
class MyClass {
    var score:String;

    public function new(score:haxe.extern.EitherType<String, Int>) {
        // technically there's no need for an if-else in this particular case, since there's
        // no harm in calling `Std.string()` on something that's already a string
        if (Std.is(score, String)) {
            this.score = score;
        } else {
            this.score = Std.string(score);   
        }
    }
}
```

However, I wouldn't recommend this approach, `haxe.extern.EitherType` is essentially `Dynamic` under the hood, which is bad for type safety and performance. Also, `EitherType` is technically only intended to be used on externs.

A more type-safe, but also slightly more verbose option would be `haxe.ds.Either<String, Int>`. Here you'd have to explicitly call the enum constructors: `new MyClass(Left("100"))` / `new MyClass(Right(100))`, and then use [pattern matching](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-pattern-matching.html) to extract the value.

---

An [abstract type](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract.html) that supports [implicit conversions](https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-implicit-casts.html) from `String` and `Int` might also be an option:

```
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var s1:Score = "100";
        var s2:Score = 100;
    }
}

abstract Score(String) from String {
    @:from static function fromInt(i:Int):Score {
        return Std.string(i);
    }
}
```

---

Finally, there's also [an experimental library](https://github.com/jcward/haxe-overload) that adds overloading support with macros, but I'm not sure if it supports constructors.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use type parameter

```
class MyClass<T> {
    var score:String;

    public function new(score:T) {
        this.score = Std.string(score);
    }
}
```

You can also use type parameter at constructor

```
class MyClass {
    var score:String;

    public function new<T>(score:T) {
        this.score = Std.string(score);
    }
}
```

However, T used at constructor fails at runtime (CS and Java), it is not fixed yet (Haxe 4). Otherwise, you could do this

```
class MyClass {
    var score:String;

    @:generic public function new<@:const T>(score:T) {
        this.score = Std.is(T, String) ? untyped score : Std.string(score);
    }
}
```

which nicely produce code like this (CS)

```
        __hx_this.score = ( (( T is string )) ? (score) : (global::Std.@string(score)) );
```

causing Std.string() to be called only if T is not a String.

Answer (score 1):

Hej,

With a simple example as it is, you can just do something like that `function new( ?s : String, ?n : Int ){}` and Haxe will use the correct argument by type. But you'll be able to do `new()` and maybe you don't want.